# AWS IoT policy doesn't allow Cognito WebSocket client to subscribe to topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I've got the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-2:672904080113:topic/x/a/b"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-2:672904080113:topicfilter/x/a/b"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is assigned to a certificate as well as cognito user ID and pool. With the physical device and with a mosquito client I am able to subscribe and to publish to the topic `x/a/b`.

The problem is, I'm not able to subscribe to the same topic from the WebSocket client. Publishing works everywhere.

If I set the resource of `iot:Subscribe` to `*` then I can subscribe to topics from the WebSocket client too and it starts getting messages. Why is that?

Comment: Add "iot:Receive" below io:subscribe

Comment: Doesn't work. Also, `iot:Receive` is already allowed for `arn:aws:iot:eu-west-2:672904080113:topic/x/a/b`.

Comment: You can check what all comes under "*" do a hit and trial maybe?